# Vespa - ReturnCode(NO_SPACE, External feed is blocked due to resource exhaustion: in content cluster)

Tags: vespa, vector-database, datafeed

Facing error while feeding data to vespa - ReturnCode(NO_SPACE, External feed is blocked due to resource exhaustion: in content cluster 'neighbors': disk on node 0 [vespa-tutorial] is 85.0% full (the configured limit is 75.0%). See https://docs.vespa.ai/en/operations/feed-block.html) "}) for put id:neighbors:neighbors::789: not retryable

[image]

How do I clear this node, I dont need existing data that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting this yourself, run [vespa-remove-index](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/operations-selfhosted/vespa-cmdline-tools.html#vespa-remove-index) on the content node(s).

If you are running on Vespa Cloud, [delete the application](https://cloud.vespa.ai/en/deleting-applications.html#deleting-an-application) and start over.

Regardless of how you are running this, you can also issue a delete operation on each document, or remove the schema containing the data.

Comment: did remove index using following command:
vespa-stop-services && vespa-remove-index -force && vespa-start-services

Still getting the same error.

Comment: Note that Vespa is built for operational security - the feed block message comes if the disk you are using is over the limit (see the linked document), regardless of size of the Vespa index. See https://docs.vespa.ai/en/operations-selfhosted/docker-containers.html for how to mount volumes (use a volume that is < 75% full)